# why CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE is not working after ios.cmake changes?

Tags: ios, cmake

After updating my ios.cmake file with https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake changes, the cmake macro CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE(sys/epoll.h EVENT) is not working.

I'm in macOS Mojave, so the check should be flagged to false and the include should be stopped before the linking stage. 
I already tried to force the the cmake requirede flags with set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES sys/epoll.h) 
and a bunch of other stuffs.

This is my ios.cmake file

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Xcode.cmake)

# Fix for PThread library not in path
set(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT "-lpthread")
set(CMAKE_HAVE_THREADS_LIBRARY 1)
set(CMAKE_USE_WIN32_THREADS_INIT 0)
set(CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT 1)


# Cache what generator is used
set(USED_CMAKE_GENERATOR "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" CACHE STRING "Expose CMAKE_GENERATOR" FORCE)

# Determine the cmake host system version so we know where to find the iOS SDKs
find_program (CMAKE_UNAME uname /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin)
if (CMAKE_UNAME)
    exec_program(uname ARGS -r OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION)
    string (REGEX REPLACE "^([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+).*$" "\\1" DARWIN_MAJOR_VERSION "${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION}")
endif (CMAKE_UNAME)

# Get the Xcode version being used.
execute_process(COMMAND xcodebuild -version
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE XCODE_VERSION
  ERROR_QUIET
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
string(REGEX MATCH "Xcode [0-9\\.]+" XCODE_VERSION "${XCODE_VERSION}")
string(REGEX REPLACE "Xcode ([0-9\\.]+)" "\\1" XCODE_VERSION "${XCODE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Building with Xcode version: ${XCODE_VERSION}")
# Default to building for iPhoneOS if not specified otherwise, and we cannot
# determine the platform from the CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES variable. The use
# of CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES is such that try_compile() projects can correctly
# determine the value of IOS_PLATFORM from the root project, as
# CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES is propagated to them by CMake.
if (NOT DEFINED IOS_PLATFORM)
  if (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES)
    if (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES MATCHES ".*arm.*")
      set(IOS_PLATFORM "OS")
    elseif (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES MATCHES "i386")
      set(IOS_PLATFORM "SIMULATOR")
    elseif (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES MATCHES "x86_64")
      set(IOS_PLATFORM "SIMULATOR64")
    elseif (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES MATCHES "armv7k")
      set(IOS_PLATFORM "WATCHOS")
    endif()
  endif()
  if (NOT IOS_PLATFORM)
    set(IOS_PLATFORM "OS")
  endif()
endif()
set(IOS_PLATFORM ${IOS_PLATFORM} CACHE STRING
  "Type of iOS platform for which to build.")
# Determine the platform name and architectures for use in xcodebuild commands
# from the specified IOS_PLATFORM name.
if (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "OS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM iphoneos)

  # This causes the installers to properly locate the output libraries
  set (IOS_PLATFORM_LOCATION "iPhoneOS.platform")
  set (CMAKE_XCODE_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS "-iphoneos")

  if(NOT IOS_ARCH)
    if (XCODE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 10.0)
      set(IOS_ARCH armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e)
    else()
      set(IOS_ARCH armv7 armv7s arm64)
    endif()
  endif()
 elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "OS64")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM iphoneos)
  if(NOT IOS_ARCH)
    if (XCODE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 10.0)
      set(IOS_ARCH arm64 arm64e)
    else()
      set(IOS_ARCH arm64)
    endif()
  endif()
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "SIMULATOR")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM iphonesimulator)

  # This causes the installers to properly locate the output libraries
  set (IOS_PLATFORM_LOCATION "iPhoneSimulator.platform")
  set (CMAKE_XCODE_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS "-iphonesimulator")

  if(NOT IOS_ARCH)
    set(IOS_ARCH i386)
  endif()
  message(WARNING "SIMULATOR IS DEPRECATED. Consider using SIMULATOR64 instead.")
elseif(IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "SIMULATOR64")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM iphonesimulator)
  if(NOT IOS_ARCH)
    set(IOS_ARCH x86_64)
  endif()
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "TVOS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM appletvos)
  if(NOT IOS_ARCH)
    set(IOS_ARCH arm64)
  endif()
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "SIMULATOR_TVOS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM appletvsimulator)
  if(NOT IOS_ARCH)
    set(IOS_ARCH x86_64)
  endif()
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "WATCHOS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM watchos)
  if(NOT IOS_ARCH)
    if (XCODE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 10.0)
      set(IOS_ARCH armv7k arm64_32)
    else()
      set(IOS_ARCH armv7k)
    endif()
  endif()
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "SIMULATOR_WATCHOS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM watchsimulator)
  if(NOT IOS_ARCH)
    set(IOS_ARCH x86_64)
  endif()
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid IOS_PLATFORM: ${IOS_PLATFORM}")
endif()
message(STATUS "Configuring iOS build for platform: ${IOS_PLATFORM}, "
  "architecture(s): ${IOS_ARCH}")


# Setup iOS developer location unless specified manually with CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT
# Note Xcode 4.3 changed the installation location, choose the most recent one available
exec_program(/usr/bin/xcode-select ARGS -print-path OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_XCODE_DEVELOPER_DIR)
set (XCODE_POST_43_ROOT "${CMAKE_XCODE_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Platforms/${IOS_PLATFORM_LOCATION}/Developer")
set (XCODE_PRE_43_ROOT "/Developer/Platforms/${IOS_PLATFORM_LOCATION}/Developer")
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT)
    if (EXISTS ${XCODE_POST_43_ROOT})
        set (CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT ${XCODE_POST_43_ROOT})
    elseif(EXISTS ${XCODE_PRE_43_ROOT})
        set (CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT ${XCODE_PRE_43_ROOT})
    endif (EXISTS ${XCODE_POST_43_ROOT})
endif (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT)
set (CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT} CACHE PATH "Location of iOS Platform")


# Find and use the most recent iOS sdk unless specified manually with CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT)
    file (GLOB _CMAKE_IOS_SDKS "${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT}/SDKs/*")
    if (_CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
        list (SORT _CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
    # Don't reverse sort the list.  The shortest name is the generic SDK which is the one we want.
    #   list (REVERSE _CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
        list (GET _CMAKE_IOS_SDKS 0 CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT)
    else (_CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
        message (FATAL_ERROR "No iOS SDK's found in default search path ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT}. Manually set CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT or install the iOS SDK.")
    endif (_CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
    message (STATUS "Toolchain using default iOS SDK: ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT}")
endif (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT)
set (CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} CACHE PATH "Location of the selected iOS SDK")

# Set the sysroot default to the most recent SDK
set (CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} CACHE PATH "Sysroot used for iOS support")


# If user did not specify the SDK root to use, then query xcodebuild for it.
execute_process(COMMAND xcodebuild -version -sdk ${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM} Path
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT_INT
     OUTPUT_QUIET ERROR_QUIET
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
# If user did not specify the SDK root to use, then query xcodebuild for it.
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT OR (NOT CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT STREQUAL CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT_INT))
  execute_process(COMMAND xcodebuild -version -sdk ${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM} Path
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT
    ERROR_QUIET
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
endif()
if (NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT})
  message(SEND_ERROR "Please make sure that Xcode is installed and that the toolchain"
  "is pointing to the correct path. Please run:"
  "sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
  "and see if that fixes the problem for you.")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT: ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} "
  "does not exist.")
elseif(DEFINED CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT)
  message(STATUS "Using manually set SDK path: ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} for platform: ${IOS_PLATFORM}")
else()
   message(STATUS "Using SDK: ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} for platform: ${IOS_PLATFORM}")
endif()
# Specify minimum version of deployment target.
if (NOT DEFINED IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)
  if (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "WATCHOS" OR IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "SIMULATOR_WATCHOS")
    # Unless specified, SDK version 2.0 is used by default as minimum target version (watchOS).
    set(IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "2.0"
            CACHE STRING "Minimum iOS version to build for." )
  else()
    # Unless specified, SDK version 8.0 is used by default as minimum target version (iOS, tvOS).
    set(IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "8.0"
            CACHE STRING "Minimum iOS version to build for." )
  endif()
  message(STATUS "Using the default min-version since IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET not provided!")
endif()
# Use bitcode or not
if (NOT DEFINED ENABLE_BITCODE) 
  # Unless specified, disable bitcode support by default
  set(ENABLE_BITCODE FALSE CACHE BOOL "Whether or not to enable bitcode")
  message(STATUS "Disabling bitcode support by default. ENABLE_BITCODE not provided!")
else ()
  message(WARNING "BITCODE support enabled.") 
endif()

# Use ARC or not
if (NOT DEFINED ENABLE_ARC)
  # Unless specified, enable ARC support by default
  set(ENABLE_ARC TRUE CACHE BOOL "Whether or not to enable ARC")
  message(STATUS "Enabling ARC support by default. ENABLE_ARC not provided!")
endif()
# Use hidden visibility or not
if (NOT DEFINED ENABLE_VISIBILITY)
  # Unless specified, disable symbols visibility by default
  set(ENABLE_VISIBILITY FALSE CACHE BOOL "Whether or not to hide symbols (-fvisibility=hidden)")
  message(STATUS "Hiding symbols visibility by default. ENABLE_VISIBILITY not provided!")
endif()
# Get the SDK version information.
execute_process(COMMAND xcodebuild -sdk ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} -version SDKVersion
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE IOS_SDK_VERSION
  ERROR_QUIET
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
# Find the Developer root for the specific iOS platform being compiled for
# from CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT.  Should be ../../ from SDK specified in
# CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT.  There does not appear to be a direct way to obtain
# this information from xcrun or xcodebuild.
if (NOT CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT)
  get_filename_component(IOS_PLATFORM_SDK_DIR ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} PATH)
  get_filename_component(CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT ${IOS_PLATFORM_SDK_DIR} PATH)
endif()
if (NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT})
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT: "
    "${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT} does not exist.")
endif()
# Find the C & C++ compilers for the specified SDK.
if (NOT CMAKE_C_COMPILER)
  execute_process(COMMAND xcrun -sdk ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} -find clang
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_C_COMPILER
    ERROR_QUIET
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  message(STATUS "Using C compiler: ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
endif()
if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER)
  execute_process(COMMAND xcrun -sdk ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} -find clang++
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
    ERROR_QUIET
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  message(STATUS "Using CXX compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
endif()
# Find (Apple's) libtool.
execute_process(COMMAND xcrun -sdk ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} -find libtool
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE IOS_LIBTOOL
  ERROR_QUIET
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
message(STATUS "Using libtool: ${IOS_LIBTOOL}")
# Configure libtool to be used instead of ar + ranlib to build static libraries.
# This is required on Xcode 7+, but should also work on previous versions of
# Xcode.
set(CMAKE_C_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY
  "${IOS_LIBTOOL} -static -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY
  "${IOS_LIBTOOL} -static -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> ")
# Get the version of Darwin (OS X) of the host.
execute_process(COMMAND uname -r
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION
  ERROR_QUIET
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

# Standard settings.
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION ${IOS_SDK_VERSION} CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(UNIX TRUE CACHE BOOL "")
set(APPLE TRUE CACHE BOOL "")
set(IOS TRUE CACHE BOOL "")
set(CMAKE_AR ar CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_RANLIB ranlib CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE)

set (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release") 

# Force unset of OS X-specific deployment target (otherwise autopopulated),
# required as of cmake 2.8.10.
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "" CACHE STRING
  "Force unset of the deployment target for iOS." FORCE)
# Set the architectures for which to build.
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES ${IOS_ARCH} CACHE STRING "Build architecture for iOS")

if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)
    set (CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.0")
endif (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)

set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL[variant=Release] "s")

# Set the find root to the iOS developer roots and to user defined paths
set (CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT} ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} CACHE string  "iOS find search path root")

# Change the type of target generated for try_compile() so it'll work when cross-compiling
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# All iOS/Darwin specific settings - some may be redundant.
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "lib")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".dylib")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX "lib")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_SUFFIX ".so")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ABI ELF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ABI ELF)
set(CMAKE_C_HAS_ISYSROOT 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_HAS_ISYSROOT 1)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_EXISTS 1)
set(CMAKE_DL_LIBS "")
set(CMAKE_C_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG "-compatibility_version ")
set(CMAKE_C_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG "-current_version ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG "${CMAKE_C_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG "${CMAKE_C_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG}")

set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "")

if(IOS_ARCH MATCHES "((^|, )(arm64|arm64e|x86_64))+")
  set(CMAKE_C_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR 8)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR 8)
  message(STATUS "Using a data_ptr size of 8")
else()
  set(CMAKE_C_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR 4)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR 4)
  message(STATUS "Using a data_ptr size of 4")
endif()

message(STATUS "Building for minimum iOS version: ${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}"
               " (SDK version: ${IOS_SDK_VERSION})")
# Note that only Xcode 7+ supports the newer more specific:
# -m${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM}-version-min flags, older versions of Xcode use:
# -m(ios/ios-simulator)-version-min instead.
if (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "OS" OR IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "OS64")
  if (XCODE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 7.0)
    set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS
      "-mios-version-min=${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
  else()
    # Xcode 7.0+ uses flags we can build directly from XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM.
    set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS
      "-m${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM}-version-min=${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
  endif()
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "TVOS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS
    "-mtvos-version-min=${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "SIMULATOR_TVOS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS
    "-mtvos-simulator-version-min=${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "WATCHOS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS
    "-mwatchos-version-min=${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
elseif (IOS_PLATFORM STREQUAL "SIMULATOR_WATCHOS")
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS
    "-mwatchos-simulator-version-min=${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
else()
  # SIMULATOR or SIMULATOR64 both use -mios-simulator-version-min.
  set(XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS
    "-mios-simulator-version-min=${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
endif()
message(STATUS "Version flags set to: ${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS}")

if (ENABLE_BITCODE)
  message(WARNING "BITCODE support enabled.")   
  set(BITCODE "-fembed-bitcode")
  set(HEADER_PAD "")
  set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_BITCODE ON)
  message(STATUS "Enabling bitcode support.")
else()
  set(BITCODE "")
  set(HEADER_PAD "-headerpad_max_install_names")
  set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_BITCODE OFF)
  message(STATUS "Disabling bitcode support.")
endif()

if (ENABLE_ARC)
  set(FOBJC_ARC "-fobjc-arc")
  message(STATUS "Enabling ARC support.")
else()
  set(FOBJC_ARC "-fno-objc-arc")
  message(STATUS "Disabling ARC support.")
endif()

if (NOT ENABLE_VISIBILITY)
  set(VISIBILITY "-fvisibility=hidden")
  message(STATUS "Hiding symbols (-fvisibility=hidden).")
else()
  set(VISIBILITY "")
endif()

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS
"${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS} ${BITCODE} -fobjc-abi-version=2 ${FOBJC_ARC} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
# Hidden visibilty is required for C++ on iOS.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
"${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS} ${BITCODE} ${VISIBILITY} -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 ${FOBJC_ARC} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0 -g ${BITCODE} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DNDEBUG -Os -ffast-math ${BITCODE} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -ffast-math ${BITCODE} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DNDEBUG -O3 -ffast-math ${BITCODE} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS} -Wl,-search_paths_first ${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS}  -Wl,-search_paths_first ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS}")

# In order to ensure that the updated compiler flags are used in try_compile()
# tests, we have to forcibly set them in the CMake cache, not merely set them
# in the local scope.
list(APPEND VARS_TO_FORCE_IN_CACHE
  CMAKE_C_FLAGS
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
  CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS
  CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS)
foreach(VAR_TO_FORCE ${VARS_TO_FORCE_IN_CACHE})
  set(${VAR_TO_FORCE} "${${VAR_TO_FORCE}}" CACHE STRING "")
endforeach()

set(CMAKE_PLATFORM_HAS_INSTALLNAME 1)
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-rpath @executable_path/Frameworks -rpath @loader_path/Frameworks")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_C_FLAGS "-dynamiclib ${HEADER_PAD}")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_CREATE_C_FLAGS "-bundle ${HEADER_PAD}")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_LOADER_C_FLAG "-Wl,-bundle_loader,")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_LOADER_CXX_FLAG "-Wl,-bundle_loader,")
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".dylib" ".so" ".a")

# Hack: if a new cmake (which uses CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL) runs on an old
# build tree (where install_name_tool was hardcoded) and where
# CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL isn't in the cache and still cmake didn't fail in
# CMakeFindBinUtils.cmake (because it isn't rerun) hardcode
# CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL here to install_name_tool, so it behaves as it did
# before, Alex.
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL)
  find_program(CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL install_name_tool)
endif (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL)

# Set the find root to the iOS developer roots and to user defined paths.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT} ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}
  ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} CACHE string  "iOS find search path root" FORCE)

# Default to searching for frameworks first.
set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK FIRST)
# Set up the default search directories for frameworks.
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH
  ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library/Frameworks
  ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks
  ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/Developer/Library/Frameworks)
# Only search the specified iOS SDK, not the remainder of the host filesystem.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# This little macro lets you set any XCode specific property.
# macro(set_xcode_property TARGET XCODE_PROPERTY XCODE_VALUE XCODE_RELVERSION)
#   set(XCODE_RELVERSION_I "${XCODE_RELVERSION}")
#   if (XCODE_RELVERSION_I STREQUAL "All")
#     set_property(TARGET ${TARGET} PROPERTY
#     XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_${XCODE_PROPERTY} "${XCODE_VALUE}")
#   else()
#     set_property(TARGET ${TARGET} PROPERTY
#     XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_${XCODE_PROPERTY}[variant=${XCODE_RELVERSION_I}] "${XCODE_VALUE}")
#   endif()
# endmacro(set_xcode_property)


# This macro lets you find executable programs on the host system.
macro(find_host_package)
  set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
  set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY NEVER)
  set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE NEVER)
  set(IOS FALSE)
  find_package(${ARGN})
  set(IOS TRUE)
  set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY)
  set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
  set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
endmacro(find_host_package)

# This little macro lets you set any XCode specific property
# macro (set_xcode_property TARGET XCODE_PROPERTY XCODE_VALUE)
#     set_property (TARGET ${TARGET} PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_${XCODE_PROPERTY} ${XCODE_VALUE})
# endmacro(set_xcode_property)

#This macro sets the unittest properties
macro (set_xcode_properties_for_unittest TARGET)
    set_xcode_property (${TARGET} GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS[variant=Debug] "YES")
    set_xcode_property (${TARGET} STRIP_STYLE[variant=Debug] "all")
    set_xcode_property (${TARGET} STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT[variant=Debug] "NO")
    set_xcode_property (${TARGET} SEPARATE_STRIP[variant=Debug] "NO")
    set_xcode_property (${TARGET} DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING[variant=Debug] "NO")
    set_xcode_property (${TARGET} COPY_PHASE_STRIP[variant=Debug] "NO")
    set_xcode_property (${TARGET} ENABLE_TESTABILITY[variant=Debug] "YES")
endmacro (set_xcode_properties_for_unittest)


function(add_ios_gtest_lib)
    set(options GTEST)
    set(one NAME DIR)
    set(multi SOURCE LIBS)
    cmake_parse_arguments("PARAM" "${options}" "${one}" "${multi}" ${ARGN})
    check_input(VAR PARAM_NAME MESSAGE "NAME was not specified for add_ios_gtest_lib")
    check_input(VAR PARAM_SOURCE MESSAGE "no SOURCE specified for add_ios_gtest_lib")

    foreach(src ${PARAM_SOURCE})
        if (DEFINED PARAM_DIR)
            set(base_filename "${PARAM_DIR}/")
        endif()

        set(local_cpp_path "${base_filename}${src}.cpp")
        set(local_mm_path "${base_filename}${src}.mm")
        set(local_h_path "${base_filename}${src}.h")
        if (EXISTS "${local_mm_path}")
            set(LOCAL_SOURCES ${LOCAL_SOURCES} ${local_mm_path})
        elseif (EXISTS "${local_cpp_path}")
            set(LOCAL_SOURCES ${LOCAL_SOURCES} ${local_cpp_path})
        endif()
        if (EXISTS "${local_h_path}")
            set(LOCAL_SOURCES ${LOCAL_SOURCES} ${local_h_path})
        endif()
    endforeach()
    add_library("${PARAM_NAME}.gtest.module" ${LOCAL_SOURCES})

    set(local_libs ${local_libs} ${PARAM_LIBS})
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Linking ${PARAM_NAME}.gtest.module with: ${local_libs}")
    target_link_libraries(${PARAM_NAME}.gtest.module PUBLIC ${local_libs} gtest)
    set_xcode_properties_for_unittest(${PARAM_NAME}.gtest.module)

endfunction()

# https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16695
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE ON)
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED OFF)

# find_package can't find bison from the Xcode toolchain. We could override the FindBISON module, but keep it simple for now.
set(YACC_EXE /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bison)

set(XCODE_BUILD "-destination generic/platform=iOS")
```

This is some parts of the CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -O0")

[...]
include(CheckIncludeFile)
include(CheckIncludeFiles)

[...]
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE(sys/epoll.h EVENT__HAVE_SYS_EPOLL_H)


CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS_EX(epoll_create EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL)
CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS_EX(epoll_ctl EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL_CTL)
CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS_EX(epoll_create1 EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL_CREATE1)

[...]

if(EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL)
    list(APPEND SRC_CORE epoll.c)
endif()
```

Configuration Log

```
xcodebuild -configuration Debug \  
   -UseNewBuildSystem=NO \
   -scheme ProjectXPluginVpnOpenssl \ 
   -project [...]projectx_ios.xcodeproj \
   -derivedDataPath target/xcode-ios/DerivedData \ 
   -parallelizeTargets \ 
   -sdk iphoneos User defaults from command line: IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /[...]/DerivedData

UseNewBuildSystem = NO 
Build settings from command line: SDKROOT = iphoneos12.1
Prepare build 
note: Using legacy build system
```

The error generated is

```
[...]/third-party/libevent/epoll.c:39:10: fatal error: 'sys/epoll.h' file not found #include <sys/epoll.h>
1 error generated. 

Build fails with the command: CompileC [...]Debug-iphoneos/event_static.build/Objects-normal/armv7/epoll.o [...]/third-party/libevent/epoll.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

The generated file event-config.h.cmake has the following entries about epoll:

```
/* Define if your system supports the epoll system calls */
#cmakedefine EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `epoll_create1' function. */
#cmakedefine EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL_CREATE1 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `epoll_ctl' function. */
#cmakedefine EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL_CTL 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/epoll.h> header file. */
#cmakedefine EVENT__HAVE_SYS_EPOLL_H 1
```

The `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE(sys/epoll.h EVENT)` should be flagged, but is not. 
Please, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You want us to find error in the toolchain which has 500 lines of code, really? Actually, even the problem is not clear. What do you mean by "the check should be flagged and the include should be stopped before the linking stage."? As MacOS doesn't support `epoll`, the header should be absent and `EVENT` should be set to FALSE-like value. Am I right? What actual value of that variable you observe?

Comment: @Tsyvarev i'm trying to find the error for more than 2 weeks, so yes, i'm asking for help. The check should flag the event to false, and now is doing the opposite, like the sys/epoll.h was found (even though when compiling the error that I get is that is not found) setting the flag to true.

Comment: Show the `CMakeLists.txt` script (in form of [mcve]), which uses given `check_include_file` call and checks its result. Try to remove CMake cache and run configuration process again. Show output of that configuration process (I see the script is pretty verbose, why do not check what it prints?). Then, under build directory should be `CMakeOutput.log`, which contains exact commands executed by `check_include_file` and resulted messages. Check that commands and messages.

Comment: Show **configuration log** (started with CMake detecting the compilers) and content of `CMakeOutput.log`. If the latter is quite big, **minimize** your `CMakeLists.txt` and repeat. BTW, strictly speaking, the file `epoll.c` is added after checking for `EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL` variable, which is set by `CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS_EX(epoll_create EVENT__HAVE_EPOLL)` call. Not with `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE(sys/epoll.h EVENT)` as you have described in the question post.

Comment: And the macro `CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS_EX` is implemented **manually** by [libevent](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/cmake/CheckFunctionExistsEx.cmake) without using `CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS` provided by CMake.

Comment: As you can see, the comments are bad for multiline logs and other text. Why do not add the log to the question post? Note, that on Stack Overflow the comments are second class citizen: the question post itself should contain all information which describes the problem. Comments are used only for request more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days searching to fix this problem, I found the lines that were giving me the headaches:

```
# Set the find root to the iOS developer roots and to user defined paths
set (CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT} ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} CACHE string  "iOS find search path root")

# Change the type of target generated for try_compile() so it'll work when cross-compiling
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

They mess with the place that the compilers go to find the frameworks...